# Why TypeError: Can't read undefined'map' property?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

contanier.js

```
class PatientListContainerNew extends Component {
  
  state = {
    limit: 7,
    file: {
      info: null,
      base64: null,
    },
    data: [],
    filteredData: [],
    columns: [],
    searchInput: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
    console.log("========componentDidMount====== ");
    const { getPatient, loadingTrue } = this.props;
    loadingTrue();
    setTimeout(() => {
      getPatient();
    }, 500);
  }
  

  ... code skip


getData = () => {
  const originData = this.props.results;
  const data = this.props.results.map((datum) => ({...datum, id: datum.id, name: datum.name}));
  this.setState({ data, filteredData: data });
};

handleSetData = data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({ filteredData: data });
};


  render() {
  const { filteredData, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <PatientSearch
          data={this.state.data}
          handleSetData={this.handleSetData}
        />
        <List
          columns={columns}
          originData={filteredData}
          limit={this.state.limit}
        />
        <input />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  results: state.patient.results,
});
```

error code

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
PatientListContainerNew.getData
D:/src/containers/patient/Container.js:346
  343 | 
  344 |    getData = () => {
  345 |      const originData = this.props.results;
> 346 |      const data = originData.map((datum) => ({...datum, id: datum.pid, name: datum.pid}));
      | ^  347 |      this.setState({ data, filteredData: data });
  348 |    };
  349 |
```

origindata holds the data from the database.

want to know why the map error is coming up.
I am confused how to use the map function. I think I used it wrong. We would appreciate it if you let us know how to use it correctly.

I'll add more code if necessary.

Thank you to everyone who answers.

Add photo

[image]

Comment: Check `this.props.results` is coming or not. It looks like its not coming out. That's why its giving error

Comment: originData is not iterable. you should check what value originData has at the time of mapping through it

Comment: this.props.results holds the data!

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting the data you expect. One way to fix this is to use the constructor to provide an empty dataset in state:

```
class PatientListContainerNew extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      originData = this.props.results || [];
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can work on this.state.originData without the error occurring.

Comment: thank you for the reply. But the data from origindata must be displayed!

Comment: If you are passing results as a prop, it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that, you are getting proper data in "this.props.results"
I think you are not getting proper data or not relatable to property using map.

Comment: The photo I added is the one running console.log (this.props.results)!